# Measure of dispersion for dataset with zero mean

Tags: coefficient-of-variation, dispersion

I'm testing a machine learning algorithm which, until now used coefficient of variation in order to relative measure dispersion among different attributes in a given dataset. 
Now that I need to test it thoroughly on larger dataset, it's critical to do something about the possibility of a zero mean, which would immediately breaks down coefficient of variation (cv), and hence the algorithm. Please note that the distributions are not essentially Gaussian, and are often skewed when they are. Also, the measure of dispersion needs to be dimensionless.

I searched the web a bit to find ways to 'normalize' cv in some manner, or to even find an alternative to cv. I tried inter-quartile range(iqr), but there was a significant drop in performance when I migrate from cv to iqr.

Is there any other dispersion measure that returns similar values to that of cv? If not, is there any principled way to 'normalize' coefficient of variance?

Comment: why not work with something like standard deviation, or since the mean is known to be zero, the root mean square, or just the mean absolute value?

Comment: Because I need the measure to be comparable to one another. Even normalized standard deviation, even if dimensionless, is not comparable to the normalized standard deviation of a different dataset. I am using ad-hoc and 'hackish' methods right now. But I am looking for a more principled way to do it.

Comment: That does not make much sense, because variability is necessarily defined in terms of units

Answer (score -4):

You have really pointed out one of the limitations of the coefficient of variation as a dispersion measure. However, I have one alternative measure of dispersion to recommend regarding this problem of getting the zero mean. although it has not been peer-reviewed, I am certain that **STATISTICAL MIRRORING** (Abdullahi, 2020) could be an appropriate alternative.

For instance, suppose you have a dataset: *-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.*
The mean, standard deviation, and coefficient of variation equal to *0, 3.3166, and #DIV/0!* respectively. But, using statistical mirroring, you would get an answer to be *-100%* (i.e, the spread around the mean is perfectly equal and opposite direction as a mirror image of each other) and *0.00%* (i.e, little dispersion around the mean) for the meanic proximity and meanic deviation respectively.

**Reference:**

Abdullahi, K.B. Optinalytic (Statistical) Mirroring: A New Novel Approach of Measure of Dispersion. Preprints 2019, 2019110268 (doi: 10.20944/preprints201911.0268.v1).

Or you can wait for a more detail explanation about statistical mirroring by following the up-coming version of the Preprint.

Sincerely,

Comment: Which journal has accepted this? Meanwhile, please extend your answer to give more detail. Answers here should be self-contained to the extent possible: supporting references are fine, but an answer should not depend on reading external sources.  On the face of it you are examining symmetry or asymmetry, not dispersion or relative dispersion.

Comment: For those who might be curious, here is the beginning of the paper's exposition: "In the statistical inferences of comparative optinalysis between two or more set of sequences, there can exist a reflector sequence (the object or source sequence) and reflecter sequence (the image sequence) such that the reflector sequence momentarily reflects in an optinalytic and intermetric manner on reflecter sequence for inferencial comparisons about their degree or level of similarity or dissimilarity." I confess I cannot make any sense of this and found no clarification in the rest of the manuscript.